# gradle shadowJar task is not finding class org.apache.tools.zip.ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, gradle, ant, uberjar, shadowjar

I am running into issue of building my project. It used to work fine, but when I build it now it fails on shadowJar task, with a class not found exception. No dependency got added. It used to work with Gradle 3.3, but now when I try with gradle 4.10, it keep failing with below error. Also If I remove line "mergeServiceFiles('META-INF/services')", then this exception doesn't occur.

This is my task definition

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar


shadowJar.archiveName=project.name+'-service-'+rootProject.version+'.jar'
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles('META-INF/services')
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'ProjectName1',
            'Implementation-Version': rootProject.version,
            'Main-Class': 'io.vertx.core.Launcher',
            'Main-Verticle': 'com.xyz.ClassName1'
    }
}
```

Error is :

```
* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':components:projectName1'.
  > org/apache/tools/zip/ZipOutputStream
 
  * Exception is:  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':components:projectName1'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:176)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:181)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/zip/ZipOutputStream
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.ServiceFileTransformer.$getStaticMetaClass(ServiceFileTransformer.groovy)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.ServiceFileTransformer.<init>(ServiceFileTransformer.groovy:57)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar.transform(ShadowJar.java:115)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar.mergeServiceFiles(ShadowJar.java:152)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar.mergeServiceFiles(ShadowJar.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:382)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:59)
    at build_43m3rudz6xctzbkf5uh8fmuo6$_run_closure5.doCall(/home/scm/jenkins/workspace/SMP.il-content-middleware-service.PR-OPENED.BUILD/components/service/build.gradle:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:528)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:78)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:370)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:83)
    at build_43m3rudz6xctzbkf5uh8fmuo6.run(/home/scm/jenkins/workspace/SMP.il-content-middleware-service.PR-OPENED.BUILD/components/service/build.gradle:136)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
    ... 62 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.zip.ZipOutputStream
    ... 86 more
 
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 4.443 secs
```

Comment: How do you apply the `shadow` plugin? Could you please include it into your question?

Comment: @thokuest  thanks, I updated the question with details of plugin "apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'   "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying few different options, I found that I am using gradle shadow jar plugin version 1.2.3. I tried upgrading the plugin version to 2.0.4 and this problem is not occurring with this plugin version. There could be more better ways to solve this problem, but for now I am unstuck.  Please post other solutions also.